# Rename .csv file and tried to open immediately gives option to open Read Only mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssis

I found a weird behavior on my system while renaming my test6.csv file and immediately tried to open it then my Microsoft Excel gave me three options :

1. Read Only
2. Notify
3. Cancel

Basically I was investigating a problem occurred in my SSIS job which failed with error saying

> "The process cannot access the file
>   '\\share\ABCD\UploadFiles\20180614_025323_test6.csv'
>   because it is being used by another process."

Flow of System is -

1. User uploads file - **Successful**
2. ASP.NET MVC Controller saves this file on shared location and renames it - **Successful**
3. SSIS Job identifies this file and read its content and process as per instruction - **Failed**

Initially I though it may be because MVC Controller is not closing its handler due to which it may be causing issue but later I found MVC Controller is using HttpPostedFile which we need not to close explicitly as request ends it will be closed. (Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9316876/698127)

Here is file save code which is called by MVC Controller Action

```
private bool TryProcessFileUpload(HttpFileCollection files, out FileUploadInfo fileInfo, out string generatedFileName)
        {
            fileInfo = null;
            generatedFileName = string.Empty;
            if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
                return false;

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            HttpPostedFile file = files[0];
            if (file != null)
            {
                  fileInfo = new FileUploadInfo(GetFileName(file.FileName), User.Identity.Name);
                  string gfn = fileInfo.GenerateFileName();
                  generatedFileName = gfn;
                  var fileSaveToPath = GetFileStoragePath(gfn);
                  file.SaveAs(fileSaveToPath);

                  return true;
            }            

            return false;
        }
```

I need help to solve my main problem i.e. SSIS and keen to understand the .csv rename behavior if anyone knows.

Comment: Curious how large the CSV file is that you're testing with.

Comment: In you `if (file != null)` code-block, why do you need to read the file? Also, did you try closing the stream once read like `stream.close()`?

Comment: @STLDeveloper file size is less than 1MB

Comment: @Aamol if I'm not wrong you are not closing your stream after renaming the file. First, you have to close stream then you can access your file.

Comment: @AD8 I have removed the unnecessary code and updated in question. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't seem to close your stream after editing the file. The file is then still in use by another operation after the script ends. Put your stream code in a using block. That will automatically close the stream and makes it possible to open your file with read/write rights.

```
using( /* stream goes here */ )
{

}
```

Comment: @Aamol what do you mean with "find my updated code"?